NestJS build not properly compiling tsconfig.paths pointing to index.ts
I've got a NestJS app with compilerOptions.paths specified as follows:
    "paths": {
      "@core/interceptors": [
        "core/interceptors/index.ts"
      ]
    }

Then I import it like this in controllers:
import { ResponseValidationInterceptor } from '@core/interceptors';

There are no errors in IDE, but when I try to serve the app, I got prompted with following error:
Error: Cannot find module '../../core/interceptors/index.ts'
When I check the dist/ folder, I can see in the controller file, the path to import the interceptor looks const interceptors_1 = require("../../core/interceptors/index.ts");
I tried using module-alias npm package, by specyfing addAlias('@core/interceptors', 'core/interceptors/index.js'); after list of imports in my main.ts file, but it doesn't have any effect.
How can I adjust my tsconfing.json or tsconfig.build.json to properly compile this path?

The path should be a folder, not a specific file, read the docs here
Here is the example I use paths:
 "paths": {
      "@model/*": ["src/model/*"]
    },

